# Pycharm not detecting Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS as WSL interpreter

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros

I am trying to use ROS Noetic with Python using WSL interpreter. But for some reason, Pycharm is not detecting Ubuntu 20.04 distro which is installed on my Windows system via WSL, and is only detecting Ubuntu 22 which was previously installed on my system.

[image: ubuntu]

I already tried setting Ubuntu 20.04 as the default distro for WSL and also uninstalled Ubuntu 22.

Also tried updating Pycharm Professional but with no luck.

I can't use Ubuntu 22 since ROS Noetic isn't supported on it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Update:

I fixed it myself. Apparently, in order for Pycharm to detect a WSL distro, the project folder should be initialized inside the distro itself. For example: /mnt/c/Users/Username/project

Comment: Update:

I fixed it myself. Apparently, in order for Pycharm to detect a WSL distro, the project folder should be initialized inside the distro itself.

For example:
/mnt/c/Users/Username/project